# how to manage DB info and Board uploaded files between a production and a development server?

Tags: php

I'm using Apache, PHP and MySQL. I maintain websites to connect to a real server remotely. But I want to separate real and development Server.

I will use Github and make a local development environment. Then I will maintain websites on local system  and send source files to Github and a real server.

I'm curious. Source files will be placed on Github. Then how to manage database info files and Board Uploaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the `.gitignore` file.

Say uploaded files.. they only mean something to production if they are uploaded in production. They only mean something to dev if they are uploaded in dev. If git is set to ignore this directory then it won't allow you to add/commit/push these uploaded files.

For database and config files, we generally name them like config.php.dist (.dist for distribution) and then rename them on the production side. Then you will always have a base config file with the necessary information which does not override what is in production and being used. Then on dev config you set your settings to reflect dev environment & dev database. In production you reflect proper.

Here is some documentation on using gitignore: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I ask one more. When I make a new local system, I will recieve souces from github. how to recieve board uploaded files? only from real server I can recieve them?